# Value assignment to multiple cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with three columns `A, B, and C`. I would like to create a new column `D` in `df`based on the value of column `C`. If the value of a pandas record in column `C` is in `values` list, I want the value of corresponding cell in column `D` set to 1, otherwise 0.

```
# df: given dataframe
# values: given list 
df["D"] = None #Creating a new column
df.loc[~df[df["C"].isin(values)].index]["D"] = 1
df.loc[df[df["C"].isin(values)].index]["D"] = 0
```

But, when I check the column `D`, the value assignment did not occur and all its cells are equal to None. I'm wondering if anybody can advice me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Try `df['D'] = df['C'].isin(values).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.loc` to fill column D

```
df['D']=1
df.loc[df["C"].isin(values),"D"]=0
```

Comment: thanks it worked! but even without creating and initializing column D first (I mean without the first line of your code)! Do you know why it is not necessary?

Comment: @woody actually you applied two condition for 0 and 1 so what I did in first line i put 1 in D column and then applied only one condition for 0